# How inherit some part of javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Firstly I'm not sure if this title is right, then i'm sorry if not.

Let's suppose I've declared a method called `foo();` and it could throw two exceptions, one from some `java.lang` class and the other from my own code. How can I inherit the java lang exception part in javadoc?

```
    /**
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException want inherit, maybe {@inheritDoc} ?
     * @throws FileNotFoundException my own doc
     * 
     */
    public void foo() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
        if (foo)
            wait(); // this I want to copy from java.lang package
        else 
            throw new FileNotFoundException(); // This I can describe why
    }
```

Comment: `{@inheritDoc}` will work, if your javadoc generation links to the Java SE javadoc.  If generating from the command line, you would use `-link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`.  Every IDE and build tool has a means of specifying the equivalent of that.

Comment: @VGR thank you, would you can give an code snippet how to do that?

Comment: Not sure inheriting the doc makes sense here. You should not be explaining what `InterruptedException` is, you should be explaining why `foo()` would throw it.

Comment: @SkinnyJ but the definition that I will write is the same as wait() has. Is that a good reason to inherit?

Comment: `{@inheritDoc}` won't look at your code.  It only copies from a direct superclass (or implemented interface).  If you don't extend or implement anything, `{@inheritDoc}` won't do anything (and may even result in an error).

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe `@see` but really I would just say something like "if the thread is interrupted while waiting for Godot"